# Getting Error while exporting

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcmap

I am making an addin to create subsets and export them to a new workspace. I have stepped through my program and getting error at this particular line while running the addin:

```
pExportOp.ExportFeatureClass((IDatasetName)pFeatureClassName, 
        pQueryFilter, pSelSet, pGeometryDef, (IFeatureClassName)pOutDatasetName, 0);
```

Can someone help that what the error could be.

Comment: Can you be sure to remember to tag your questions with the `arcobjects` tag when you are using that API?

Comment: can you post your exact error message here?

Comment: @ vinayan :: Actually, I am not getting any error in visual studio IDE I can successfully deploy my addin but when I run it, it gives error as "ArcGIS desktop has encountered a serious application error and is unable to continue.", I debugged my code step by step and found that the error is due to the following line::

pExportOp.ExportFeatureClass((IDatasetName)pFeatureClassName, pQueryFilter, pSelSet, pGeometryDef, (IFeatureClassName)pOutDatasetName, 0);

Please Help...!!!

Comment: are you trying to export from one geodatabase to other? or gdb to shapefile? did you try to put a try-catch block and see what the exception message gives when you debug?

Answer (score 1):

[It is a comment basically. Because of the code line is not supported in comment, I posted it as an answer.]

Please be sure about following lines:

```
pFeatureClassName as IDatasetName != null 
pOutDatasetName as IFeatureClassName != null
```

Comment: @ emi :: I added following 'if' condition and it checked that these two are not null and I am still getting error...

if ( (IDatasetName)pFeatureClassName != null && (IFeatureClassName)pOutDatasetName != null)
{pExportOp.ExportFeatureClass((IDatasetName)pFeatureClassName, pQueryFilter, pSelSet, pGeometryDef, (IFeatureClassName)pOutDatasetName, 0);}

Comment: please be sure any data is not null. This ArcGIS crash problem occurs when you try to do any invalid thing with arcObject API.